# WSO2 API is sending request to 172.17.0.2 which is Dockers internal IP

Tags: docker, wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am running WSo2 in Docker and am trying to create an API that will hit existing SOAP endpoint. I could create and publish API but noticed that curl is sending request to 172.17.0.2 which i know is my docker container's ip address
I don't see any place to configure correct IP address. 
Where can i configure IP address to my SOAP service host machine?

I am not able to find any place to configure correct IP for Production and Sandbox environment.

curl -k -X POST "https://172.17.0.2:8243/TestInterface/TestInterfaceService/sendTransaction/v1.0.0/" -H "accept: text/xml" -H "Content-Type: text/xml" -H "Authorization: Bearer fc6c84f2-5e2d-3e9e-bdea-a9cbf142fe82" -d "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:tri=\"[http://www.AAAA.com/BBB/\](http://www.AAAA.com/BBB/%5C)">    ......
 
"

Comment: `curl is sending request` This part is not clear. Are you not creating the curl request yourself?

Answer (score 0):

By default, it takes the container ip for the gateway endpoint.

You can change the gateway IP/host by changing the value defined in api-manager.xml file which resides in APIM_HOME/repository/conf location. In that file, there is tag called APIGateway and inside that, there is another tag called gatewayEndpoints. For gateway endpoints, you can use a hostname or an IP address. Please refer https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Changing+the+Hostname